# Unity Hub still thinks version is installed when its not

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity hub believes that Unity version 2019.4.26f1 is installed when no existence of it on my computer exists, everytime I press uninstall it reappears next time I open Unity Hub. I've restarted my computer, uninstalled Unity Hub and restarted and it always appears. I can't redownload the version because it says it already exists on my computer which it doesn't because when I check open in explorer even Unity acknowledges that the file path doesn't exist. What do I do? How do I tell Unity that if something doesn't exist that means it doesn't bloody exist

Comment: I checked the log files and there's an error log which says {"moduleName":"UnityInstallStepsWindows","level":"warn","message":"[ 'An error occured while deleting registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\\\Software\\\\Unity Technologies\\\\Installer\\\\Unity 2019.4.26f1. Ignoring: Error: Command failed: reg delete \"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\\\Software\\\\Unity Technologies\\\\Installer\\\\Unity 2019.4.26f1\" /f\\nERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.\\r\\n' ]","timestamp":"2021-09-16T01:31:08.158Z"}

Comment: Do you have a lot of Unity versions installed? Otherwise I would try to just uninstall and reinstall UnityHub itself ... However, if you already have quote an amount of Unity versions installed via the Hub it would be quite annoying to either reinstall them all or having to restore the rest of registry keys so they are linked correctly again ...

Comment: Alternatively try to install any other Unity version, find the registry key for that version (you now know where to look for it) and just try to manually recreate the one for your missing Unity version just so the Hub can finally remove it ^^ Possible that these registry keys store also the path to the installation .. so if necessary you could create according folder and copy in the files from another versions installation .. it doesn't have to be able to run .. we only need stuff the Hub can remove correctly :'D

Comment: Report it as an issue to unity so they can fix it

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this same issue, I was able to download a Unity version without using hub (so an exe) and created a file named the same as the missing location that Unity hub was looking for and put the exe into it. I can't change the file location, its forever stuck on my desktop so thanks Unity for your amazing intelligent system...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Still broken in 2022. Can't remove 2019.3.0a8

Comment: Uninstall UnityHub entirely and reinstalled but still there

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you would have updated the `editors.json` manually. You need to change the contents of that file so that it will reflect in the editor.

1. Go to this path

```
C:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Roaming\UnityHub\
```

2. Find editors.json there
3. Remove the `key:value` pair of the version you want to remove from the Hub.

I hope it helps!